# The ring of integers of a locally compact non-archimedean field is compact

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

I am not looking for a solution, I want **an enlightening hint**.

Let $K$ be a locally compact complete non-archimedean metrizable field. Then $\mathcal{O}_K=\{x\in K: |x| \leq 1 \}$ is compact. Is $\{x\in K: |x| < 1 \}$ necessarilly compact?

Comment: One way to argue about this I believe is proving that if $K$ local field, then $\mathcal O_K$ is profinite (and every profinite is locally compact)

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, that's essentially the definition of "locally compact".

Comment: Note: This question was changed after I wrote my answer. The new question is kind of answered in comments under my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "enlightening hint" should probably be: What does "locally compact" mean? It means that certain small balls are compact, and if certain balls are compact, you can scale them to bigger balls which are still compact. And what you wrote down there is a closed unit ball.

Actually, it is quite easily seen that a normed vector space over a field with a non-trivial valuation is locally compact iff its closed unit ball is compact. Cf. [Locally compact vector spaces over non-Archimedean field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4064233/96384). The statement here is, if not the definition, then the case of dimension $1$, and if anything proven easier than the general statement.

Comment: It seems the solution is very easy. I know the definition of the concept of locally compact, but yet I can not conclude.

Comment: Where's the problem? By definition of "locally compact", the element $0$ has a compact neighbourhood $C$. By definition of neighbourhood, that one contains some closed ball of some radius $r$ around $0$. Do you see that that ball is compact? And then scale $r$ to $1$, as in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have to think more to understand these things better to resolve my confusions. I have to review almost every concept for myself.

Comment: What are the open sets? Is this set $\{ B(0, r): r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ a union of basic opens around the origin?

Comment: If $B(0, r) = \{x \in K: \lvert K \rvert < 0\}$ (the open ball of radius $r$ around $0$), then for each $ r > 0$, that is a basic open set around $0$. Yes, maybe review basics of how a value (or norm) defines a metric, and how a metric defines a topology. (Also, watch out: It will turn out here, unlike in the usual metric on $\mathbb R$, that the "open" ball is open (by definition) *but also closed* (in the topology), and the "closed ball"  $\{x \in K: \lvert K \rvert \le 0\}$ is closed *but also open* in the topology. You don't need any of that for this proof but it's good to know.)

Comment: Can we modify this argument to show that $\{x\in K: |x| < 1 \}$ is also compact?

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment, in both sets, it should say $\lvert K \rvert < \color{red}{r}$ and $\lvert K \rvert \le \color{red}{r}$, respectively. Then of course the case $r=1$ is included.

Comment: I got your opinion and I noticed this typo at that moment. But I can not see whether this open set is compact or not? I know zero has a compact neighborhood. But I can not continue.

Comment: Well, closed subsets of compact sets are compact. So if you believe that e.g. $\{x \in K: \lvert x \rvert \le 2 \}$ is compact, and you believe the non-trivial fact mentioned that $\{x \in K: \lvert x \rvert <1\}$ is not only open, but also closed, then ...

Comment: I think your argument needs the discreteness of the value group $|K^{*}|$. If we have the discreteness of the value group, then we can find a suitable $1<c$, such that there is no element with the norm between $1$ and $c$. And then we consider $\{x \in K: \lvert x \rvert \leq c\} \setminus \{x \in K: \lvert x \rvert <1\}$, and your argument works.

Comment: I realized how to conclude the discreteness. It is very simple. Thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: Discreteness indeed gives an extra argument as outlined by you. The statement is true for any non-archimedean absolute value though, discrete or not: Namely, if $x$ is in the complement $C$ of $B(0,r)$, say, then by the strong triangle inequality the entire $B(x, r/2) = \{y \in K: \lvert x-y\rvert < r/2 \}$ is also contained in $C$, hence $C$ is open, hence $B(0,r)$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I got the point.