# Matrices preserving the sup-norm on $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Consider the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $n\geq 1$.
The absolute value is $|x|=p^{-v_p(x)}$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}_p$, where $v_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation.

Endow $V=\mathbb{Q}_p^n$ with the sup-norm:
For $v\in V$, $\|v\|=\max_{i=1}^{n} |v_i|$.

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

> Does the condition $v_p(\det A)=0$ imply that $\|Av\|=\|v\|$ for all $v\in V$? Is $v_p(\det A)=0$ also a necessary condition?

This is trivially true in the case $n=1$, and maybe I'm grossly generalizing, but I think this has a change of being true.

Comment: What about matrices of the form $\pmatrix{c & 0\cr 0 & 1/c}$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: This forces $v_p(c)=0$ (as $A$ has entries in $\mathbb{Z}_p$), and so they preserve the norm. Am I right?

Comment: Too late an hour for me to think straight, but it seems to me that shears preserve the norm. Doesn't this imply the claim given that the Smith normal form of $A$ is necessarily the identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and more: The subgroup of those elements of $GL_n(K)$ which leave the sup-norm invariant is exactly $GL_n(\mathcal{O}_K)$, for any local field $K$ with its ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Cf. reuns' answer to [Natural Extensions of the $p$-Adic Norm to Higher Dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3259966/96384) . (And for any commutative ring $R$, $GL_n(R) =\{g\in M_n(R): \mathrm{det}(g) \in R^\times\}$. Cf. also [Compact subgroups of $p$-adic fields and the groups $GL_n$ over them](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4487795/96384) .)

Comment: I understand now why the elements of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathcal{O}_K)$ preserve the sup-norm. But you are also saying that no other element of $\operatorname{GL}_n(K)$ preserves the sup-norm. Why is that?

Comment: @Object: I would think if $A$ is a matrix with $|a_{ij}| > 1$, and you multiply it with the unit vector $e_j$, you get a vector whose sup-norm is $>1$.